# Select command using webmatrix

Tags: mysql, sql, webmatrix

I'm using Webmatrix 3

I have the following code for obtaining session `var session_username = Session["session_username"];`

Now, I want to search for a username from my database like the variable `session_username`.

I'm using the following code to execute the query `var selectcommand = "SELECT * from student where student_username = @session_username";
var row = db.Query(selectcommand);`

It's giving an error `Exception Details: System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException: A parameter is missing. [ Parameter ordinal = 1 ]` for the line `var row = db.Query(selectcommand);`

What am I doing wrong? Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be

```
var selectcommand = "SELECT * from student where student_username = @0";
var row = db.Query(selectcommand, session_username);
```

This tutorial explains the use of the parameter placeholders: [Introduction to Working with a Database in ASP.NET Web Pages (Razor) Sites](http://www.asp.net/web-pages/tutorials/data/5-working-with-data).